# NullReference Exception in TreeNode.get_Handle() in OwnerDrawn TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have customized the appearance of TreeVIew in C#.NET by setting

```
DrawMode=OwnerDrawAll;
```

That is,

```
OnDrawNode()
```

is overridden and drawn each node and connection lines successfully. Every thing is working fine except, I am getting a NullReference excpetion frequently. The below is the stack trace

```
at System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode.get_Handle()
at System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode.get_RowBounds()
at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.CustomDraw(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WmNotify(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
The message send to the WndProc during the exception is "WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message message = {msg=0x204e (WM_REFLECT + WM_NOTIFY)).
```

Frequently I am getting this exception for the following steps:

1. Add 2 nodes with large text to the treeview.
2. Set the RightToLeft and RightToLeftLayout properties to true.
3. Remove all nodes using "Nodes.Clear()" API.
4. Again add 2-3 nodes with large text in the tree view.

Any one have any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Can you share the code where you build the tree?

Comment: Adding nodes to `treeview` at a certain time (such as when the Form is invisible) may cause this exception.

Comment: @KingKing The form is visible always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is found that the

```
TreeNode.get_Handle()
```

throwing null reference exception during the notification about custom draw. I didn't get the reason for the exception. But I have solved it by handling the null reference exception in "NM_CUSTOMDRAW" 
notification message.